# Rules stop executing while Outlook displays Modal Dialog

Tags: outlook, rules

I am using the Outlook legacy app on MacOS.  I have set up rules in my client app on my desktop to execute whenever an email arrives.  I use the legacy app because it allows me to move messages between different email accounts.

I recently set up and turned on an out-of-office message for the next few months.  Unfortunately, every day or so, Outlook puts up a modal dialog that asks, "Do you want to turn off Office messages?".   Until I click "No", the client app will not execute any of the rules I have set up.   How can I stop these modal dialogs from appearing and stopping my rules from executing?

[image: Outlook Turn Off Out of Office Dialog]